# Sqlite3 Accessing a specific record from a database from a different class and putting it into a tkinter entrybox

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

The function of this code is that it displays the list of records in a database with one of the fields being a button. When this button is clicked it brings the user to a new frame which displays the account information for that record.

The record information is displayed in the Record class as dat[0] and dat[1] and I have had problems with initializing this in the second class, I do not know how I would get this information to appear on the second screen.

Thanks for any help.

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
import AddAccount
import RemoveAccount
import LogOnLib
import LoginMenu
import TrainerAccounts


class Records(object):
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        window.state("zoomed")
        self.window.title('Trainer Accounts')
        window.update_idletasks()

        h = self.window.winfo_height()
        w = self.window.winfo_width()
        Center_h = h/2
        Center_w = w/2

        self.FrameRecords = Frame(window, bg = "PaleTurquoise1")
        self.FrameRecords.place(x = Center_w , y = Center_h, anchor = "center", width = 1024, height = 300)

        self.btn_Back = Button(self.FrameRecords, text = "Back", bg = "PaleTurquoise1", font =("Arial", "16"), command = self.Back, width = 20)
        self.btn_Back.grid(row = 1, column = 4, columnspan = 5)

        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(r"E:\Program\Accounts.db")
        self.cur = self.connection.cursor()
        self.btn_TrainerID = Label(self.FrameRecords, text = "Trainer ID", bg = "PaleTurquoise1", font =("Arial", "16"), width = 20)
        self.btn_TrainerID.grid(row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 1)
        self.NameLabel = Label(self.FrameRecords, text = "Name", bg = "PaleTurquoise1", font =("Arial", "16"), width = 20)
        self.NameLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.showallrecords()



    def showallrecords(self):
        Data = self.readfromdatabase()


        for index, dat in enumerate(Data):
            self.row1 = Button(self.FrameRecords, text=dat[0],font =("Arial", "16"), command = self.account).grid(row=index+1, column=0)
            self.row2 = Label(self.FrameRecords, text=dat[1],font =("Arial", "16")).grid(row=index+1, column=1)




    def readfromdatabase(self):

        self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Trainers")
        return self.cur.fetchall()

        self.btn_TrainerID = self.row1
        self.NameLabel = self.row2

    def Back(self):
        self.FrameRecords.place_forget()
        GUI = LoginMenu.Logged(self.window)

    def account(self):
        self.FrameRecords.place_forget()
        GUI = TrainerAccounts.TrainerInfo(self.window, Records)
##########################################################################################################################################################################################
class TrainerInfo(Records):
    def __init__(self, window, Records):



        self.window = window
        window.state("zoomed")
        self.window.title('CHANGEEEE')
        window.update_idletasks()

        h = self.window.winfo_height()
        w = self.window.winfo_width()
        Center_h = h/2
        Center_w = w/2

        self.FrameTrainerInfo = Frame(window, bg = "PaleTurquoise1")
        self.FrameTrainerInfo.place(x = Center_w , y = Center_h, anchor = "center", width = 1024, height = 300)

        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(r"E:\Program\Accounts.db")
        self.cur = self.connection.cursor()
        self.showrecord()

    def showrecord(self):
        Data = self.Information()
        for index, dat in enumerate(Data):
            Label(self.FrameTrainerInfo, text=self.row1,font =("Arial", "16")).grid(row=index+1, column=0)
            Label(self.FrameTrainerInfo, text=self.row2,font =("Arial", "16")).grid(row=index+1, column=1)


    def Information(self):
            self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Trainers WHERE row1 = '" + row1 + "'" + "AND row2 = '" + row2 + "'")
            return self.cur.self.all()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried merging the two classes together ?

Answer (score 0):

if you can push values from database you only need make a .insert on Entrybox

maybe like this

```
tkEntry = Entry( master)
tkEntry.pack() # .grid or .place, don't make this in obj create
tkEntry.insert( 0, dat[0] ) # 0 is the index and dat[0] is your value
```